# dual monitor/projector login screen

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

if have a dual "monitor" setup, where one of the monitors actually is a projector. 
the projector is not always turned on.
the problem is, that the login screen quite often is not visible and the rather unexperienced users do not know how to login then. yes, you would just have to move the mouse to the left or right and then the login screen appears.

anyway, is there a way to change the login screen to clone mode, which actually works well after login?

thanks
thomas